# Bond length in hydrogen chloride

Tags: bond

> The interatomic distances in $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ are $74$ and $\pu{198 pm},$ respectively. Find the bond length of $\ce{HCl}.$
>
> **a**. $\pu{136 pm}$
> **b**. $>\pu{136 pm}$
> **c**. $<\pu{136 pm}$

According to me, if $\ce{HCl}$ was a non polar molecule then the bond length would simply be

$$\frac{\pu{74 pm} + \pu{198 pm}}{2} = \pu{136 pm}$$

But as there is polarity the electrostatic force of attraction should reduce the bond length to less than $\pu{136 pm}.$

However, the answer is exactly $\pu{136 pm}.$ I do not understand why.

Comment: I suppose they have used the simplified approach, using general covalent atom radius. The true radius is 127.4 pm.